# BeautifulSoup doesn't find line

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the length of a YouTube video with BeautifulSoup and by inspecting the site I can find this line: `<span class="ytp-time-duration">6:14:06</span>` which seems to be perfect to get the duration, but I can't figure out how to do it.

My script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uQrJ0TkZlc")

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html5lib")
mydivs = soup.findAll("span", {"class": "ytp-time-duration"})

print(mydivs)
```

The problem is that the output is `[]`

Comment: Sorry for the title. It should be "BeautifulSoup doesn't find line"

Comment: I found it. Thank you

Comment: `soup.find("span", {"class": "ytp-time-duration"}).text` ? Side note: Youtube (and any google products) have powerful anti-scrapping measures, so be careful to not get blocked

Comment: Unfortunately the output is still None.

Comment: first check `print(response.text)` - maybe you get warning message that server doesn't like bots/scripts and send you captcha. OR maybe page uses JavaScript to add this element - BeautifulSoup can't run JavaScript.

Comment: @furas has a good point. Did you check your `soup` object? It's quite likely that Youtube uses reCaptcha v3, which is veeeeery difficult to bypass (also developed by Google). Anyways there's a Youtube API that might let you get that kind of information "legally"

Comment: I'm pretty sure that that's a JavaScript element. So that's probably the reason. Do you know a library which can read JavaScript elements?

Comment: you can use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser which can run JavaScript. It needs more time to get data because browser has to load all data and render it but it behaves like human  so it may have less problems with captcha.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

soup.findAll('div', attrs={"class":u"ytp-time-duration"})

But I guess that your syntax is a shortcut, so I would probably consider that when loading the youtube page, the div.ytp-time-duration is not present. It is only added after loading. Maybe that's why the soup does not pick it up.